# Multiple Buttons on Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-button, fragment-lifecycle

In a fragment when buttons are clicked on, they will open different fragment. When signup_b is clicked, new fragment is opened but when signin_b is clicked new fragment is not opened.

```
 public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    signin_b = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signup_b = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
    //signin_b.setOnClickListener(this);
    //signup_b.setOnClickListener(this);
    signup_b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick (View v){

            question = new RegisterQuestionFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment,question,"information").addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
    signin_b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick (View v){

            log = new LoginFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment,log,"log").addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is error message? Please update your question with log.

Comment: Which fragment is the one that you posted? is it by any chance the LoginFragment?